# Whats the difference between $_foo and _foo in php?

Tags: php, variables

What is the difference between `$_foo` and `_foo` in php?

Comment: One is a variable, the other is "assumed" to be a constant. Why are you asking this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first refers to a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) named `_foo`. The second refers to a [global constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) named `_foo`.

By default PHP will issue low-severity errors when you try to access an undefined variable or [undefined constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php). In such cases, the "value" of the variable will be assumed to be `null` while the "value" of the constant will be assumed to be the stringified version of its name -- in this case, `'_foo'`.

Comment: One thing to add: if PHP doesn't find a constant, PHP assumes it to be a string without quote!

Comment: @ComFreek: Was editing to mention this. Thanks for the input.

Comment: "The second refers to a global constant named _foo"
Wrong, _foo (single underscore) is a protected method, double underscores is a private method

Comment: @XToro Just because that's a naming convention you use does not make it a hard and fast rule of the core language. Did you know there is a native function called `_()`?

Comment: Although I will be pedantic and pick my own hole in this, technically `_foo` refers to an *identifier* - it may refer to a function, class, interface etc, and is not necessarily global when namespaces are taken into account.

Comment: @DaveRandom yeah gettext, but that's what a naming convention is for, and if php itself uses it, then it should be used that way

Comment: What is the difference between $_foo and $foo then? Sorry I am such a newbie.

Comment: @fall `$foo` and `$_foo` are just two different variables.

Comment: I usually use $foo for general variables, under what circumstances do we choose to use $_foo as a variable name?

Answer (score -1):

Variables are preceeded by a dollar sign ($).  The underscore that preceeds a method (without a dollar sign) indicates it's protected, double underscore means it's private, they can't be called externally.

Comment: Explained here : [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)